# Get value of named character vector element when name is NA

Tags: r, vector

Suppose I have a named character vector like this:

```
> class(colors)
[1] "character"

> colors
       9074        8778        8577        7148        <NA>        3310     0050169        8893       50156        9008        9778 
"#FF0000FF" "#FF7600FF" "#FFEB00FF" "#9DFF00FF" "#27FF00FF" "#00FF4EFF" "#00FFC4FF" "#00C4FFFF" "#004EFFFF" "#2700FFFF" "#9D00FFFF" 
       5295     0080162 
"#FF00EBFF" "#FF0076FF"
```

where the names are IDs, and the values are colors. If I give an ID to the `colors` vector, I get the corresponding color.

```
> colors["9074"]
       9074 
"#FF0000FF"
```

However for the one case where the name is `<NA>`, I do not know how I can return the corresponding color. Simply providing `NA` does not work

```
> colors[NA]
<NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> 
  NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA 

> colors["NA"]
<NA> 
  NA
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe `colors[is.na(names(colors))]`? I really don't know.

Comment: Define "does not work".  What output are you expecting?

Comment: Does not work as in does not return the corresponding color. I think that is pretty clear. But @RuiBarradas that works! many thanks. Please write it as an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `colors` already is the name of a `base R` function, I will create a vector `x`.

```
x <- 1:5
names(x) <- c("A", "B", NA, "D", "E")

x[is.na(names(x))]
#<NA> 
#   3
```

Comment: “Since colors already is the name of a base R function” — this is fairly irrelevant. Name shadowing is frequent and unproblematic. Don’t try to avoid it, it leads to convoluted, artificial names.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I disagree. I've many times problems with the use of base R functions as variable names. Most of all, `c`, needing `get(c)`, but also of others.

Comment: You don’t need (nor should you use) `get('c')` (it also wouldn’t work, you’d need `get('c', envir = baseenv())` or something similar). You use `base::c`. That’s what namespaces *are for*. That said, shadowing `c` in a scope where `base::c` is also needed may indeed be ill-advised. But in general it’s fine: you can’t seriously consider banning general names such as `colors`, `plot` etc. from your entire code base.

Comment: @KonradRudolph No, sorry, I wasn't clear. `get(c)` was needed to get the variable, not the function.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, but would return multiple values if multiple colors don't have names.

```
colors[which(is.na(names(colors)))]
```

Comment: No need for `which`. It’s redundant.